# Finding What point the mouse is over going too slow

Tags: c#, wpf

Ok, so right now when i click on the grid it goes through all the 'paths' on the grid and checks if they're an ellipse and if the mouse is over them, and if there's 2 selected it calculated the distance apart.... but if i get 50+ points on the grid, clicking on a point does nothing.... Is there any more efficient way of doing this ?

Here's my code:

```
foreach (var x in GraphPanel.Children)
{
     try
     {
         if (((Path)x).IsMouseOver && ((Path)x).Data.ToString() == "System.Windows.Media.EllipseGeometry")
         {
            listViewPoints.SelectedItems.Add(listViewPoints.Items[PointIndex]);
            var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
            var brush = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFB1D100");
                    ((Path)x).Stroke = brush;
                    ((Path)x).StrokeThickness = 8;

            if (listViewPoints.SelectedItems.Count == 2)
            {
                 double diffX;
                 double diffY;

                 double ptAX = ((Points)listViewPoints.SelectedItems[0]).A;
                 double ptAY = ((Points)listViewPoints.SelectedItems[0]).B;
                 double ptBX = ((Points)listViewPoints.SelectedItems[1]).A;
                 double ptBY = ((Points)listViewPoints.SelectedItems[1]).B;

                 if (ptAX > ptBX)
                 {
                     diffX = ptAX - ptBX;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     diffX = ptBX - ptAX;
                 }
                 if (ptAY > ptBY)
                 {
                     diffY = ptAY - ptBY;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     diffY = ptBY - ptAY;
                 }
                 //the distance between the points = sqr/-diff in x squared + diff in y squared
                 double result = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(diffX,2) + Math.Pow(diffY,2));
                 CalculatedDistanceApart.Content = "Distance Apart: " + result.ToString() + "'";
             }
        }

        if (((Path)x).Data.ToString() == "System.Windows.Media.EllipseGeometry")
        {
            PointIndex++;
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know about your slow `IsMouseOver`, but the whole thing can certainly be sped and tidied up:

```
//why make these for every item?
var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter(); 
var brush = (System.Windows.Media.Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFB1D100"); 

foreach (var x in GraphPanel.Children) 
{ 
    //this is tidier, but what if it's not a Path, is that possible?
    var path = (Path)x;

    //jump out here if it's not the right type, reduces nesting and removes one comparison
    if(!(path.Data is System.Windows.Media.EllipseGeometry)) continue;

     try
     {
         if (path.IsMouseOver)
         { 
            listViewPoints.SelectedItems.Add(listViewPoints.Items[PointIndex]); 
            path.Stroke = brush; 
            path.StrokeThickness = 8;      
            if (listViewPoints.SelectedItems.Count == 2) 
            {
                 double ptAX = ((Points)listViewPoints.SelectedItems[0]).A; 
                 double ptAY = ((Points)listViewPoints.SelectedItems[0]).B; 
                 double ptBX = ((Points)listViewPoints.SelectedItems[1]).A; 
                 double ptBY = ((Points)listViewPoints.SelectedItems[1]).B; 

                 //you're going to square these, so negatives don't matter
                 double diffX = ptAX - ptBX;
                 double diffY = ptAY - ptBY;

                 //the distance between the points = sqr/-diff in x squared + diff in y squared 
                 //don't use Math.Pow for squaring
                 double result = Math.Sqrt(diffX*diffX + diffY*diffY); 
                 CalculatedDistanceApart.Content = "Distance Apart: " + result + "'"; 
                 //are we done now?
             } 
        } 
        PointIndex++; 

    } 
    catch { } 
}
```

[Math.Pow(x,2) vs x * x](http://bytewrangler.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/mathpowx2-vs-x-x.html)

Comment: Continuing if it's not a geometry, good thinking!
 'why make these for every item?' It only makes it when it finds the path it's over (it can only be over 1 path) so it runs only once :o

Comment: OK this actually made a huge difference, every time i click a point now it's instantly selected

Comment: Your old code did the `IsMouseOver` even if it was not an `EllipseGeometry` because it was the first part of the `&&`. That is probably the biggest difference in my version. If it can be only over one, then why not also `break` out of the loop after the first "hit" for an extra optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a Path you could add ellipses to the grid and just attach a [MouseLeftButtonUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup.aspx) event handler to each ellipse.

You wouldn't need all this hit-test code.

Comment: I'm not manually drawing ellipses, they get added programmatically, And I've already used features of a path in my code to draw the points in the correct location, Is there perhaps a better way without changing my paths to ellipses?

Comment: I am afraid not. The idea behind the Shapes opposed to the Geometries is that they add exactly that; the hittest. So if you do not use the shapes you will have to do the processing yourself and my guess is that that will be slower.

Comment: I'm gonna attempt to write a threaded solution and see if that makes any difference, and if it doesn't i suppose i can convert my code to not use paths, I don't remember why i used paths to start with (since i wrote the code a long time ago) but i'm assuming i had a good reason :o

Comment: Building a threaded solution will be hard because you are accessing the UI which only can be done on the UI thread. It will only work if you have the data available without needing to go back to the UI elements.